# Not compatible with your operating system or architecture: fsevents@2.1.3

Tags: firebase, npm, npm-install, firebase-admin

I am using ubuntu 18.04.4 LTS
I was trying to learn admin sdk tutorials from google codelab, and was trying to setup the defined project in [this](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/firebase-admin/index.html?index=..%2F..index#3)

While setting up, the following command gives an error.
`npm -g install firebase-tools`
and error: "No firebase command found" on command `firebase --version`

I have tried setting npm settings globally as described [here](https://docs.npmjs.com/resolving-eacces-permissions-errors-when-installing-packages-globally), but nothing works.

Can anyone help me with this, as I am new to firebase admin SDK.

Comment: nodejs is probably not installed correctly, or there is a problem with your shell path.  But if you are trying to work with the Firebase Admin SDK, there is actually no need to install the CLI.  The Admin SDK is a node module that you include in your code to work with Firebase products programmatically.

Answer (score 0):

Shouldn't you first install firebase itself?

```
npm i -g firebase
```

Comment: I have tried. Still same error appears "firebase: command not found".

Comment: There is no need to install the Firebase client SDK before installing the Firebase CLI.